# How to mock static function inside Akka Actor scope?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, akka, powermockito

I have an actor which calls a static method from a Helper I'd like to mock:

```
public class ExampleActor extends AbstractActor {
    public Receive createReceive() {
        .match(CachedFile.class, cachedFile -> {
            UploadFileHelper.makeRequest(cachedFile.getContent());
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried mocking it:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(UploadFileHelper.class)
public class ExampleActorTest {

    @Test
    public void testCreateFile() {
        new TestKit(system) {{
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(UploadFileHelper.class);
            PowerMockito.when(
                UploadFileHelper.makeRequest(any())
            ).thenReturn(true);

            exampleActor.tell(cachedFile, getRef());
        }}
    }
}
```

But for any reason the real method is being called instead of the mocked one.

Is there any change I should do in order to mock static methods inside the Akka Actor context?

Comment: static methods are notoriously hard to test. Consider replacing with an instance method from the utility. All the static saves is the object construction. Pass the utility instance as a dependency to the Actor.

Comment: I'll create a service between the actor and the static methods then. Thanks!

Comment: I agree: when you can get rid of *static* easily - then get rid of it. Beyond that - your code looks OK ... i just dont get why you create a new anonymous inner class here - no idea what TestKit is about.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks, I'm following the examples of this page: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/testing.html
Do you recommend another way to test Akka Actors?

Answer (score 0):

When I use mockStatic, mockStatic in

```
"main"@1 in group "main": RUNNING
```

is ok， but it can not work in

```
"AkkaTestKit-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3"@2,614 in group "main": RUNNING
```

Just use [CallingThreadDispatcher](https://doc.akka.io//docs/akka/2.5/testing.html?language=java) when you create your Props.

```
final Props props = Props.create(ExampleActor.class).withDispatcher(CallingThreadDispatcher.Id());
```

It works for me.